# Python: consistent timing on print statements?

Tags: python, printing, timing

I wrote the following script to print consecutive integers to the terminal, overwriting the last number each time:

```py
import time

i = 0
while True:
    print(i, end="")
    time.sleep(0.25)
    print("\033[F")
    i += 1
```

However, the timing is very jittery. Sometimes it even skips a number, because it prints the next number so quickly.

Why does this happen? Is there a way to overcome this? (It doesn't have to be perfectly accurate, just enough so that it seems even.)

EDIT: I know that I can slow this down and it gets steady. That's not the point. The reason I want to do this is to make a kind of toy metronome in the terminal. So it needs to be steady going down to like 0.1 seconds.

Comment: Probably because stdout is buffered. Try flushing stdout

Comment: The print's of Python are line-buffered by default. Try to run with `python -u` to switch that off. Also don't expect the sleep time to be too accurate.

Comment: It's quite steady on my computer (2013 iMac, Python 3.9.4), regardless of buffered/unbuffered.

Comment: The code is running properly in my PC, as it does in the other guys' PCs according to the comments, so its something on your PC,

Answer (score 0):

i think better try 0.5 and limit i to stop the program.

```
import time
boolean = True

i = 0
while boolean:
    print(i, end="")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("\033[F")
    i += 1
    if i == 100:
        boolean = False
```

Comment: I fail to see how this addresses the question. Further, in Python you would loop like `for i in range(100)` rather than using a flag `boolean`.

Comment: the code of him is running normal on my pc, so I think that he can slow it down and see it properly.

Comment: Hi -- I appreciate your attempt, but it really was about being accurate when the sleeps are short.

Answer (score 0):

So I think it is, as you all have said, something about my computer/terminal setup: In particular, it's quite unsteady when I run it in a terminal inside of PyCharm, but when I ran it through a regular terminal, it was steady.

It's funny, though, because I thought I tried that last night and it wasn't steady. Maybe my computer was just tired. ;-)